# What is the reason of getting the warning: "haven't verified StreamExecutor"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am new to TensorFlow and started with the "Hello, TensorFlow!" example from TensorFlow documentation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

sess = tf.Session()

print(sess.run(hello))
```

I'm using TensorFlow through Anaconda, Windows 10, my system has 2 GPUs. After running the above code, I got the following warning:

> c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:523]
>   A non-primary context "CODE" exists before initializing the
>   StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.

After searching the web, I got many different results that are talking about other issues in the reported code, however, the warning about which I'm concerned, no one discuss it. My initial feeling was that this warning is not important. However, I looked at the TensorFlow core code, and I felt that such warning has important message to be delivered for me as a developer. Anyone, please, could tell me what is the message and what the possible effects on my TensorFlow-based project code with having such warning? Thanks in advance.